# Get UTC time in windows kernel mode

Tags: c++, windows, kernel-mode

How can i get utc time in windows kernel mode?

I'm aware of KeQuerySystemTime (but this is 1601 based).

i found this solution.

```
LONGLONG FileTime_to_POSIX(FILETIME ft)
{
    // takes the last modified date
    LARGE_INTEGER date, adjust;

    date.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
    date.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;

    // 100-nanoseconds = milliseconds * 10000
    adjust.QuadPart = 11644473600000 * 10000;

    // removes the diff between 1970 and 1601
    date.QuadPart -= adjust.QuadPart;

    // converts back from 100-nanoseconds to seconds
    return date.QuadPart / 10000000;
}
```

but this seems to be wrong, i tested it and it was round about 10 seconds wrong

Comment: [RtlTimeToSecondsSince1970](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553241(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: thanks you made may day

Comment: @RbMm that should be an answer not a comment :-)